# Retrieving autosearch values from MySQL

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, json

I have this Jquery autosearch function which brings me resuts but instead of hardcoded availableTags I would prefer to select them from a database.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#tabs").tabs();

        var availableTags = [
            "ActionScript",
            "AppleScript",
            "Asp",
            "BASIC",
            "C",
            "C++",
            "Clojure",
            "Scheme"
        ];

        $("#autocomplete").autocomplete({
            source: availableTags
        });
    });
</script>
```

Could you please propose a solution? Do I need JSON or something else?

Comment: Use AJAX to query the results from your database (returning JSON if you'd like) and supply the resulting array to the `autocomplete()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the source to a php file where you search the database and return results:

```
$("#autocomplete").autocomplete({
    source: search.php
});
```

search.php

```
//get your stuff from the database and build an array

$array = array(
   0 => array(
      "label"   => "item #1",
      "value"   => 123
   ),
   1 => array(
      "label"   => "item #2",
      "value"   => 111
   ),
   2 => array(
      "label"   => "item #3",
      "value"   => 222
   )
);

echo json_encode($array);
```

Answer (score 1):

First create index.php and write the code below.

```
<html>
<body>
<input type="text"  class="autosuggest"/><input type="submit" value="search"/>
<div class="dropdown">
<ul class="result"></ul>
</div>
<script src="jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="javascrip.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Than create javascript.js and write the code below.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.autosuggest').keyup(function() {
    var search_term=$(this).attr('value');
    $.post('search.php', {search_term:search_term},function(data){
        $('.result').html(data);

        $('.result li').click(function(){
        var result_value=$(this).text();
    $('.autosuggest').attr('value', result_value);
    $('.result').html('');
        });

         });
        });
});
```

And at last create search.php and write the code below .

```
<?php 
$con=mysql_connect('localhost','root','') or die(mysql_error());
$db=mysql_select_db('your database name');
if(isset($_POST['search_term']))
{
    $search_term=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['search_term']);
$query=mysql_query("SELECT Names FROM `name` WHERE `Names` LIKE '$search_term%'");
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($query)){
echo '<li>',$row['Names'],'</li>';
}
}
?>
```

I think this is what you are needing bro.

Comment: No problem. A friend in need is a friend indeed.